# spherical coordinates. triple integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$\int\limits_0^5 \int\limits_{\sqrt{25-x^2}}^{-\sqrt{25-x^2}} \int\limits_{\sqrt{25-x^2-z^2}}^{-\sqrt{25-x^2-z^2}}  \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dx$$

triple integral trying to change to spherical coordinates.

Comment: What is your question exactly?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: so i have to change it to spherical coordinates

Comment: and i tried doing it and got 50*pi. but the correct answer is 25* pi

Comment: theta is from 0 to 2pi. rho from 0 to 5. phi from 0 to pi. these are limits i chose. and the function is 1/(rho^2)

Comment: You should type (in [LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/107/faq-for-math-stackexchange/117#117)) all your steps out, then someone can check them.  It's impossible to see where your error is without seeing your work.

Comment: sorry i am new. i will try that. thank you

Comment: Note that $ x $ doesn't vary from -5 to 5, it varies from 0 to 5.  Your limits in spherical are thus incorrect, and this is why you are off by a factor of 2.

Comment: @AAbc: Are you sure that you copied the question correctly. I think you are missing the square root. The integrand should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

The integrals on $y$ and $z$ have their limits in an unusual way (positive below, negative above) but changing both at the same time won't change the value of the integral (as each contributes a minus sign). So we want
$$
I=\int_0^5 \int_{-\sqrt{25-x^2}}^{\sqrt{25-x^2}} \int_{-\sqrt{25-x^2-z^2}}^{\sqrt{25-x^2-z^2}}  \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,dy~dz~dx
$$
The region is the half solid sphere of radius $5$ centered at the origin, with $x\geq0$. In spherical coordinates, this is
$$
0\leq\rho\leq5,\ -\pi/2\leq\theta\leq\pi/2,\ 0\leq\phi\leq\pi.
$$
So
$$
I=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^5\frac1{\rho^2}\,\rho^2\sin\phi\,d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^5\sin\phi\,d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta=5\pi\,\int_0^\pi\sin\phi\,d\phi=5\pi\,(-\cos\phi)|_0^\pi=10\pi.
$$

edit:integral limits on the most outer integral were not correct (both were $\pi/2$, one should be $-\pi/2$ and one $\pi/2$)

Comment: The equation in the integrand should be $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \frac{1}{{\rho}^2}$.

Comment: You right. But as you said in your other comment, most likely the square root is missing, then. I've edited so far without the square root.

Comment: I got exactly the same answer as you, but I did not post it.